# Times new roman and bm in beamer

Tags: fonts, errors, bm

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Everything works with documentclass `report`. Currently, with `beamer`, I'm getting

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared. ...
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal. ...
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal. ...
```

By removing `siunitx`, I can eliminate the math errors. And by removing any of the other two, all errors disappear. But I need all to use all of these packages (a lot of my material from the corresponding `report` assumes these). How do I make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option `professionalfont` helps to reduce the font declarations by `beamer` (older versions):

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Newer `beamer` versions want a font theme instead of the option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```