# "! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared." error!

Tags: beamer, stix

I am trying to use stix font in beamer class:

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikz,stix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label =above:$C$](c) at (0,0);
\draw (c) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting that error "! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared." error!", Any ideas what is the problem?

I used the same source code inside standalone class and it worked well! I think the problem is with beamer..

and I've tried that solution [Times new roman and bm in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263310/times-new-roman-and-bm-in-beamer) but it apparently did not work, I am no longer get the error message but the text font doesn't change!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`, this disables all the things beamer normally does concerning fonts.

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=above:$C$](c) at (0,0);
\draw (c) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I referred on the post to that solution, I already tried that one and I do not get the error message anymore but yet the font doesn't change!

Comment: @AhmedHawary I get another font, see the image I added, with and without `\usepackage{stix}`. The font change may be not that obvious, as with `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` the default font is already quite similar to stix.

Comment: obviously, I am a new user, thanks for explaining that for me!